# Webpack generating empty CSS files in Laravel app when using Vue-Router

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, webpack, sass, laravel-mix

I have a `Laravel` application that uses `webpack` to compile some SASS assets.

```
mix.js('resources/js/vue/User/dashboard.js', 'public/js/User')

.js('resources/js/vue/home.js', 'public/js')
.js('resources/js/vue/admin-dashboard.js', 'public/js/admin')

.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
.sass('resources/sass/layouts.scss', 'public/css');
```

Inside one of the JS files it compiles, is a Vue-Router instance that creates webpack chunks:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: "history",
    routes: [
        {
            path: "/admin",
            component: () => import("./admin/Dashboard.vue" /* webpackChunkName: "js/admin/components/dashboard" */ )
        }
    ],
    scrollBehavior (to, from, savedPosition) {
        return savedPosition || { x: 0, y: 0 };
    }
});
```

The above code breaks the compiling of my CSS assets. When I run `npm run dev`, the output says that the CSS files are generated properly.

```
 DONE  Compiled successfully in 3177ms                                                                                                                                                                   3:16:42 PM

           Asset      Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
    /css/app.css   196 KiB     mix  [emitted]  mix
/css/layouts.css  9.91 KiB     mix  [emitted]  mix
```

However when I check the .css files, both of them are empty. If I comment out the Vue-Router portion, the CSS files generate correctly.

**Why does including the Vue-Router webpack chunks break the compiling of the CSS assets?**

Comment: could you put scss files before js files in webpack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be a problem with Laravel Mix as described in the notes section of [this release](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/releases/tag/v4.0.0) and how it deals with dynamic imports

**Notes**

---

- If your project heavily uses JavaScript dynamic imports, you may need to hold off until the release of webpack 5 early next year. There are known compile issues related to this that we cannot fix until then. Once webpack 5 is out, Mix will be updated shortly after.

This will be fixed when webpack 5 is released so the current workaround is to downgrade Laravel mix to version ^3.0

Answer (score 1):

I just replaced the way I call the components.

From:

```
component: () => import('Login')
```

To:

```
component: require('Login').default
```

And everything works fine, I'm not really sure if it's the same thing. Maybe someone can elaborate a little bit over my solution.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE OCTOBER 2020**

as **JeffreyWay** desribe here https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/1914#issuecomment-706608848

> This was a known issue with Mix and webpack 4. We tried for a long
> time to resolve it, but every option ended up breaking a different
> part of the Mix API.
>
> The problem is solved in Mix v6 which now uses webpack 5.

Tested laravel mix version v6.0.0-beta.10 **extract()** and **dynamic import**.

**routes.js**

```
function view(path) {
  return () =>
    import(
      /* webpackPrefetch: true */
      `@/views/${path}`
    ).then(module => module.default || module);
}

export default [
  {
    path: "/login",
    name: "login",
    component: view("auth/login.vue")
  },
]
```

**webpack.mix.js**

```
mix.extract();
```

Result:

[image]